using sed to replace a string between quotes '12h' by '3h'
I am trying to use sed to replace a string like '12h'  by '3h'
sed -i 's/length_s = '12h'/length_s = '3h'/g' my_files

but it didnt work

You've got a quoting problem there. You can match single quotes (') inside the expression if you're also using single quotes on the outside. Try instead sed "s/length_s = '12h'/length_s = '3h'/g" my_files.

It’s cause you have single quotes inside single quotes. The shell doesn’t know which is which. Either replace outside quotes with double quotes or escape the inside quotes to let the shell know to take them as literal quotes instead of interpreting them.
Solution 1:
sed -i "s/length_s = '12h'/length_s = '3h'/g" my_files

Solution 2:
sed -i 's/length_s = \\'12h\\'/length_s = \\'3h\\'/g' my_files

